# HTML table does not let me change table position to center when rendering as PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css, html, renderas

I'm trying to display my HTML table in the center of the page when rendering it as pdf. When I render as HTML it works as expected so I assume that CSS properties for alignment doesn't work properly in pdf. Any help on this is appreciated!

My VF Component is embedded in a VF page as below:-

```
**COMPONENT**
table.heatmapWrapper{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    table-layout: auto;
    text-align:c

    <apex:form >
            <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
            <div style="text-align:center; width:100%;" >
            <table class="heatmapWrapper" text-align="center"> <!--style="/*width:{!width}; height:{!height};*/margin: 0 auto !important;"-->

**VF PAGE**
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!showAggregatedHeatMap}">
           <!--  <div style="page-break-after:always;"></div> -->
            <c:DrawHeatmap heatmap="{!heatmap}" safeMode="true" height="500px" width="100%" disableRiskList="true" showRiskIds="true"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The PDF render engine doesn't like inline styles and  if you are using css styles, you need create a static resource with the .css and in the visualforce load de css

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MYStyless, 'vfStyles.css')}"/>
```

Comment: i'm already doing that! actually that style class is from my static resource and I use the stylesheet value as specified :( Can't understand what's blocking

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues going on with your code. The first thing I immediately see is that you're using the `<apex:form>` tag which is on the list of **Components That Are Unsafe to Use When Rendering as PDF**. See [Component Behavior When Rendered as PDF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_component_behavior.htm) in the VF Developer's Guide for a complete list of "Safe", "Use with Caution" and "Unsafe" Visualforce components.

You've not included all of the code for your entire page, so I can't say all of what else might be going on. But, I don't see an `align:center` in the `table.heatmapWrapper` CSS. The only `align:center` callouts I see are all related to text. I can also say that the Render Engine doesn't support any CSS 3, instead only CSS 2.1. 
`